# Swift. Replacing a variable's value using an extension function

Tags: swift

I want to make a function to change the original value of my variable. for example

```
class Something {
    var name:String = "   John Diggle   "
    name.trim()
    print(name)
    // prints out "   John Diggle   "

    // what I wanna do is to make it so that I don't do this
    name = name.trim()
    print(name)
    // prints out "John Diggle"
}




extension String {
   func trim() -> String{
       return self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
   }
}
```

is there a way to change the value of a variable inside a function without doing `name = name.trim()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
extension String {
    mutating func trim() {
        self = self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as `name.trim()`

Comment: Assumption: The `mutating` attribute lets the compiler know that the function cannot be called on constants?

Comment: Yes, it should be `var`, since String is a struct and not class, it cant change the value once it's let, the same with the question though, it should be `var` already, `mutating` keyword mean you try to change the value of the `self`inside the function

Comment: oh. didn't know I could use mutating func on String extensions. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on Tj3n's answer (which you should accept), the emerging convention in the API is to use the past tense of the verb (e.g. `trimmed`) to return a new string, a method you can use on both constants and variables, and use the present tense (e.g. `trim`) for the mutating rendition, which can only be used on variables:

```
extension String {

    func trimmed() -> String {
        return self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    }

    mutating func trim() {
        self = self.trimmed()
    }

}
```

Thus, either:

```
var name = "   John Diggle   "
name.trim()
print("'\(name)'")
```

Or:

```
let name = "   John Diggle   "
let trimmedName = name.trimmed()
print("'\(trimmedName)'")
```

Comment: thanks I'll keep that in mind with my naming conventions thus far

Answer (score 1):

You can use `didSet` to trim the string everytime it's changed:

```
class Something {
    var name: String = "" {
        didSet {
            name = name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
    }
}

let s = Something()
s.name = "   John Diggle     "

// Note that we never call trim in the outside code
print("'\(s.name)'")
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It's not a bad solution.

Comment: @NRitH perhaps because it's not an extension? (as per request)

Comment: This depends on assumptions that the OP did not made clear. Trimming spaces from the beginning and end of a name is a reasonable expectation. The OP asked to to mutate `name` in a single function call (instead of re-assigning it) but the end goal may have been identical

Comment: @CodeDifferent the title pretty clearly requests an extension

Comment: @NRitH - I don't think this deserved a down-vote, but it's not a good pattern, either. When you set a property, you expect it to be whatever you set it to be. It's probably not a problem in this particular case, but as a general pattern, this sort of hidden behavior becomes a maintenance annoyance. If I wanted this behavior, I'd (a) use private stored property; (b) have public method to update the value; and (c) have a computed property to retrieve the value. But that public interface should use names that make it clear that some transform may have taken place.

Comment: It's a great solution, but not what I wanted to do. but thanks this gives me an idea for another part of my code I want to shorten.

Comment: @Rob I agree that hidden manipulation generally isn't a good idea but this is a specific solution to a specific problem. It does have its uses and it should be documented. The downvoter didn't leave a comment so we may never know what's his/her reason for doing so. I respect different opinions.